# Azure SQL Server copy database script failing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

```
CREATE DATABASE {0} 
AS COPY OF {1} ( SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S2' )
```

> Execution timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   CREATE DATABASE AS Copy of  operation failed. Internal service error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If setting a higher connection timeout via the connectionstring doesn't work, you might want to check out the [Command Timout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) setting on the `SqlCommand`.

You can also set this with any of the ORM-frameworks available, though the property is probably named something different.

Answer (score 0):

You have a timeout exception, which indicates the time to complete the command is longer as your timeout. Have a look at the connectionstring to see the connection timeout. Change it to a larger value.

Depending on what takes time, you can create the db as a larger size (S3) and than scale it down afterwards. Check if the DTU usage is at 100% while creating the db.

Comment: I made it 5 min as "Server=tcp:[DB].database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={0};Persist Security Info=False;User ID=[UID];Password=[PWD];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=300;" still having timeout error in 30 seconds.